# Qmake get parent directory

Tags: qt, qmake

I try to get the parent directory for PWD.
I try ../$$PWD. It does not work.
Initially the task was to get the address of the parent subdir, but so far I can't even downgrade the directory.

```
TEMPLATE = app
Parent_path = $$PWD //here i get smt like C:/Myproject/project(here is my project.pro), but i need only C:/Myproject
```

Comment: Try this one `$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../` or `$$PWD/../`

Comment: I tried, I get the same as with $$PWD

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: I just tried `message($$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../)` and `message($$PWD/../)` and it works

Comment: Ok. `Parent_path = $$PWD/../` is a solution. I just tried to *message* it and it works

Comment: I tried, but just got $$PWD + /../ example (C:/Myproject/project/../)

Comment: This is exact what you want - parent path. `..` means parent directory.

Comment: Indeed, it actually works, thanks. Make an answer I'll mark as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to

```
Parent_path = $$PWD/../
```

OR

```
Parent_path = $$clean_path($$PWD/../)
# Where `../` is resolved.
```

Because `..` is a hard link to parent directory. Then you can use your **Parent_path** variable something like this

```
message($$Parent_path)
```